# How can I build my Expo app using SDK 49: CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod

Tags: xcode, expo, cocoapods, eas

After following [the instructions to upgrade](https://blog.expo.dev/expo-sdk-49-c6d398cdf740) my Expo app to SDK 49, I am no longer able to build locally using

```
eas build --profile dev-simulator --platform ios --local --clear-cach
```

My build aborts with the error below.

I can build remotely and run the resulting app using `expo start --dev-client --ios`.

I'm baffled why this should be the case. I've deleted my `node_modules` and rebuilt (by running `yarn`) and have launched the Xcode app and ensured that the components it offers to install have been installed.

What can I do to get my app to continue building locally?

---

- System Version: macOS 13.4.1 (22F82)
- Kernel Version: Darwin 22.5.0
- CPU: octa-core 64-bit arm_blizzard_avalanche
- Clang: 14.0.3 build 1403
- CLT: 14.3.1.0.1.1683849156
- Xcode: 14.3.1

---

```json
{
  ...
  "packageManager": "yarn@3.4.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.22.5",
    "@config-plugins/react-native-ble-plx": "^6.0.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/pro-duotone-svg-icons": "^6.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons": "^6.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/pro-regular-svg-icons": "^6.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome": "^0.3.0",
    "@fortawesome/sharp-solid-svg-icons": "^6.4.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.18.2",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "9.3.10",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "2.4.10",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
    "amazon-cognito-identity-js": "^6.3.1",
    "aws-amplify": "^5.3.3",
    "aws-amplify-react-native": "^7.0.2",
    "expo": "^49.0.0",
    "expo-dev-client": "~2.4.4",
    "expo-file-system": "~15.4.2",
    "expo-sharing": "~11.5.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.20.4",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.18.8",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.1",
    "react-native-ble-plx": "^2.0.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "~1.8.0",
    "react-native-logs": "^5.0.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.3.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.1",
    "react-native-svg": "13.9.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.1",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.22.8",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.21.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions": "^7.22.5",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-shorthand-properties": "^7.22.5",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-template-literals": "^7.22.5",
    "@redux-devtools/core": "^3.13.1",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.2",
    "@types/react": "~18.0.27",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.25",
    "@types/uuid": "^9.0.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.61.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.61.0",
    "eslint": "^8.44.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^27.2.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "jest": "^29.6.1",
    "jest-expo": "^49.0.0",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6"
  },
  ...
}
```

---

```
[INSTALL_PODS] Framework build type is static library
[INSTALL_PODS] [Codegen] Generating ./build/generated/ios/React-Codegen.podspec.json
[INSTALL_PODS] Analyzing dependencies
[INSTALL_PODS] Fetching podspec for `DoubleConversion` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec`
[INSTALL_PODS] [Codegen] Found FBReactNativeSpec
[INSTALL_PODS] Fetching podspec for `RCT-Folly` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/RCT-Folly.podspec`
[INSTALL_PODS] [Codegen] Found rncore
[INSTALL_PODS] Fetching podspec for `boost` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/boost.podspec`
[INSTALL_PODS] Fetching podspec for `glog` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec`
[INSTALL_PODS] [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "SocketRocket":
[INSTALL_PODS]   In Podfile:
[INSTALL_PODS]     React-Core (from `../node_modules/react-native/`) was resolved to 0.72.1, which depends on
[INSTALL_PODS]       SocketRocket (= 0.6.1)
[INSTALL_PODS] None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `SocketRocket (= 0.6.1)`.
[INSTALL_PODS] You have either:
[INSTALL_PODS]  * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
[INSTALL_PODS]  * mistyped the name or version.
[INSTALL_PODS]  * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.
[INSTALL_PODS] [!] `<PBXResourcesBuildPhase UUID=`13F07F8E1...B00A75B9A`>` attempted to initialize an object with an unknown UUID. `14F076057...F822C3CDB` for attribute: `files`. This can be the result of a merge and the unknown UUID is being discarded.
[INSTALL_PODS] 
Error: pod install exited with non-zero code: 31
    at ChildProcess.completionListener (/Users/Rax/.npm/_npx/2b827...8729/node_modules/@expo/spawn-async/build/spawnAsync.js:42:23)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1091:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (node:internal/child_process:449:11)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at Pipe.<anonymous> (node:net:322:12)
    ...
    at spawnAsync (/Users/Rax/.npm/_npx/2b827...8729/node_modules/@expo/spawn-async/build/spawnAsync.js:7:23)
    at spawn (/Users/Rax/.npm/_npx/2b827...8729/node_modules/@expo/turtle-spawn/dist/index.js:16:47)
    at installPods (/Users/Rax/.npm/_npx/2b827...8729/node_modules/@expo/build-tools/dist/ios/pod.js:11:38)
    at /Users/Rax/.npm/_npx/2b827...8729/node_modules/@expo/build-tools/dist/builders/ios.js:68:41
    at BuildContext.runBuildPhase (/Users/Rax/.npm/_npx/2b827...8729/node_modules/@expo/build-tools/dist/context.js:86:34)
    at buildAsync (/Users/Rax/.npm/_npx/2b827...8729/node_modules/@expo/build-tools/dist/builders/ios.js:67:19)
    at async runBuilderWithHooksAsync (/Users/Rax/.npm/_npx/2b827...8729/node_modules/@expo/build-tools/dist/builders/common.js:12:13)
    at async Object.iosBuilder (/Users/Rax/.npm/_npx/2b827...8729/node_modules/@expo/build-tools/dist/builders/ios.js:27:16)
    at async buildIosAsync (/Users/Rax/.npm/_npx/2b827...8729/node_modules/eas-cli-local-build-plugin/dist/ios.js:66:12)
    at async buildAsync (/Users/Rax/.npm/_npx/2b827...8729/node_modules/eas-cli-local-build-plugin/dist/build.js:55:29)

Build failed
Unknown error. See logs for more information.
npx exited with non-zero code: 1
    Error: build command failed.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try running `pod repo update`. It will download the updated pod version. It fixed the same problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too: CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "SocketRocket":
I can't build locally with M1 chip, and neither can eas build, but I can build locally with intel chip.
For now, I ran `pod install --repo-update` after generating the native package using prebuild

Answer (score -1):

I encountered the same issue as you but on a bare RN project. The SocketRocket Pod can be updated to the correct version by using `pod install --repo-update` as indicated in your error log.

What I did to solve this was to:

1. Remove `Pods/` folder and `Podfile.lock`. (to get a clean install)
2. Run your npm/yarn installs again.
3. cd to `ios/` and run `pod install --repo-update`

Comment: Not even sure I know what a pod is. I thought Expo abstracted away all that stuff. And should't keeping Xcode up to date keep pods uptodate as well. Why would I need to spbrpately manage individual pods?

Comment: And in any case, I don't se a `Pods` or an `ios` folder anywhere.

Comment: Right, you're using the managed workflow for Expo, which is why you do not see any native folders and code. 

This might be a reach, but if you would to switch to [bare workflow](https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/customizing/), you would be able to get access to the `Pods` folder to perform the pod updates.

After that you could probably switch back to the managed workflow since your local Podfile is synced up with the latest Pod changes. (I might be wrong but worth a shot perhaps?)

Comment: I just needed to [run `pod repo update`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76649760/656912). Not sure why or why pods got exposed in that way when I'm using managed.